# problemas com fpdf no cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Quando vou criar uma nova classe PDF estendendo-a para o FPDF para reescrever os métodos Header,Footer, etc... Me aparece esse seguinte erro, já pesquisei mas não consegui resolver..

esse é o meu método privado no controller:

http://hastebin.com/eqenexequd.coffee

e o erro que aparece é esse:

Class declarations may not be nested

Comment: O erro quer dizer que tem uma classe dentro do outro. Pode postar seu código de classe? Pode ser que realmente tem um classe dentro do outro, ou pode ser que é simplesmente um erro tipográfica.

Answer (score 0):

Você está carregando o vendor de forma correta ?.
O  vendor segue as convenções do cakephp ?.

```
App::import('Vendor', 'SomeName', array('file' => 'some.name.php'));
```

Veja a sessão: Loading Vendors em: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html